How to give super user rights to faker or spoof system
I have MUIU 14 and android 12.
I installed magisk and rooted my device. Later I installed module XPOSED and android faker. I also installed another 3rd party app called Device Id. When I use randomize function on my Android Faker and go Device Id I can see that androidId field is spoofed.(I want to spoof as much as possible, phone number, IMEI, android ID, mac adress.... whatever Android Faker offers)
But when I do the same for system application(go to settings and check the wifi mac address) I don't see any spoof happening. I believe this is because Android Faker doesnt have superuser rights or linux's security enforcement.
How do I enable this ? Has anyone used Android faker before ? It didnt ask for superuser rights when I launched the app. But something like BuildProp Editor asks for super rights.
Note: I launch XPOSED application and choose which apps to spoof for Android Faker. I also chose the app "system" in order to do that. Will post pictures shortly
This is the screenshot from LPosed:
I can activate Android Faker's "System" for spoofing. But android faker never asked for Super User rights when first launched. Doesn't it require that already ? If so why it didnt ask and how can I give it SuperUser?

This is the settings app. As an example, I want to spoof the mac address here by using  Android Faker .
But this value never gets spoofed. Even with Android Faker. (Faker spoofs other 3rd party apps but not settings.)

I need to give it superuser for that or something else?

Which MAC address are you talking about? Recent versions of Android automatically do MAC address randomization for WiFi. Via Developer Options you can make it fully randomized.

I meant IMEI and every thing that Android Faker pretty much includes

@Robert that s just for demonstration

Note that apps can not be assigned superuser permissions, they have to request them for certain operations. Then if your phone is rooted usually a UI is popping up if you allow the app superuser access.
